# Cant change value in a row

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, watir

Test should: 1.click on icon 'Edit' row (form fot password changing is apperared); 2. Type a new 'password' ; 3. Click 'OK' button in form.
How its works on Watir + Ruby :

```
browser.img(:title, "Edit").click #fire_event 'onclick'
browser.text_field(:id,"ID").set 'password' # Set new password
browser.div(:id,"ID").click # Save a password
```

And password was changed - thats ok.
But when I tried to do the same on Selenium Webdriver + C# password isnt changed.
Code:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id(...)).FindElements(By.TagName("img"))[0].Click(); // thats Edit button
driver.FindElement(By.Id(...)).SendKeys("1"); // Typed new password in row
driver.FindElement(By.Id(...)).Click(); // thats 'OK' button.
```

Guys what I did wrong? 
I hope for your help.

Comment: Why are you sending "1" rather than "password?

Comment: I tried numbers and latters. And this is doesn't matter.
Also I noticed that button 'OK' clicked and changes should be saved.
Dont uderstand why the same source-code on watir and selenium isnt works.
If anyone have any ideas I really appreciate..

Answer (score 0):

If both the textbox and button have the same ID, there's your problem.  It's impropper to have more than one instance of an ID per a page.  Even if the element type is different, it shouldn't happen.  Chrome assumes proper html therefore when you search for an element with an id of 'ID', it grabs the first instance.  Here is a work around for that issue:

1. Open page in Chrome
2. Right click and "Inspect element" on the element you want to find (one of the elements with duplicate IDs)
3. Double click on the id that shows up and delete the id='ID' part and hit enter
4. Right click on that html element again and copy xpath
5. Change the selector to driver.FindElement(By.XPath("theXpathChromeReturns"));

Also you should check out css & xpath selection for the first element.  It makes finding elements much cleaner.

```
driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#myId img")[0].Click();
```

or

```
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("img[title='edit']");
```